# Why "git pull" command over https from github repository need "sudo" as prefix?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github

My OS is ubuntu, I have some codes located on github.com, everything is ok before, but one day, when I typing:

**git pull**

I'm asked to input password as usual, and then I get this error.

**error: couldn't connect to host while accessing https://ghosert@github.com/ghosert/VimProject.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed**

until I try sudo prefix like:

**sudo git pull**

It works as before once again. It seems I lost the permission on accessing https when git need it. Anyone has idea on this?

Comment: `sudo` should not have been required; and now that you have used it, I'm afraid you've got worse problems to fix up. :) I suggest running something like: `sudo chown -R username:groupname .` in your local directory to change file ownership back to you. (Replace `username` with your username, and `groupname` with your primary groupname as listed in `/etc/passwd`.)

Answer (score 6):

The error you posted doesn't indicate that the problem was permissions.

```
error: couldn't connect to host while accessing
https://ghosert@github.com/ghosert/VimProject.git/info/refs fatal: HTTP request failed
```

"HTTP request failed" sounds like a connectivity problem.

I would simply bet that your internet connection failed when you typed it the first time, and was back up when you typed it again, with `sudo`, which I doubt had any effect on fixing the problem.

Worse, it probably messed up your permissions now, refer to sarnold's answer.

Comment: I promise the internet connection is not broken. It always fails when there is no sudo, but always works with sudo.

Another clue is that when I ssh to this machine from another machine with the same username, it still works without sudo.

Comment: Might be something in your environment. Try "su - [your username]" Does it work then?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today and here is my analysis and solution.

I set proxy settings system wide in my chrome browser for some purpose and it seems that it has created some environment variables which are causing my working shell to believe that their is no connectivity as i killed the proxy server when the job was finished. The env variables were not removed.

Check if your env has some unnecessary variables set. 
env  --this command will show all the env variables set in you shell.

**Variables:**

http_proxy, https_proxy

Remove them and everything will work.